# cannot find -lgoto while compiling on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, goto, blas

My Dear All the Greatest Lords,

It's most simple to install software packages in common use. But by means of such oversimplified routines lost control of varieties under different context of developing environments. After downloading, unzipping, plugging in the openblas2, I expect to enjoy the fortunate linear algebra computing functionality provided.

Having succeeded in compiling a bunch of codes based on them, gcc broke off by encountering the following error,

```
"cannot find -lgoto"
```

Thanks in advance for the slightest hint is the greatest bestowment to the most humble myself.

Comment: And have you [googled](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/software.php?software=LIBGOTO&all_sites=yes)?

Comment: I googled but found nothing suit my situation. Wondering if I should install gotoblas2, then to find no such package to be downloaded from any link on this site:https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/. Even tried penetrating tools brute forcing none such thing.

Comment: Yeah, looks like many of the download links are dead.  Try http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/goto/signup_first.html

Comment: You're funny, the links of the downloads are all broken.

Comment: Sorry; your question doesn't explain how you already did these things, so I assumed you had not done them. I don't know what more can be done if the library's sources are no longer available. Maybe email the Flame project and ask them? Some Github repos seemed to contain code which might be useful, but I have not examined them in any detail.

Comment: Hi, tripleee, downloaded GotoBLAS2 from github and tried to build. But reported another error. It is:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-l
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../libgoto2_barcelonap-r1.13.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/GotoBLAS2/exports'
make: *** [shared] Error 2

Comment: The error is:
gcc ...... linktest linktest.c ../libgoto2_barcelonap-r1.13.so ......  -l -l -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lm -lc   && echo OK.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-l
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You should probably post a separate question with proper diagnostics.  Maybe add an answer here with a link to the Github project where you found the sources and mark it as accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.

Comment: Hi, tripleee. I have posted another one about the question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271676/cannot-find-l-l-error-when-compiling-gotoblas2-under-ubuntu-12-04lts
Would you like to answer it?